# AWS Lambda deployment issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to deploy AWS Lambda function in root account and access a service that is in all linked accounts?

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to enable cross-account IAM access.

Comment: My requirement is I've to refresh Trusted Advisor checks through lambda, Now I have written lambda code in one account which is refreshing all checks but the point is I have to deploy function in one account and it should trigger in all 10 linked accounts. Can we do that?

Comment: Yes. You can do this using cross account IAM roles. You need to keep track of the linked accounts IAM roles in your management account (possibly in a DynamoDB).